# Logical Time, Lamport Timestamps and Vector Clocks in distributed systems

Tags: concurrency, timestamp, distributed-system, vector-clock

I am currently studying Distributed Systems for an exam. I think I have understood all the principles so far, but I go crazy when it comes to the topics of logical time, lamport timestamps and vector clocks. I just can't get an overview and connections to the topics. Here is my index card, which I would like to write...

Logical Time

- enables coordination of events without physical clock
- achieved by: ordering events into "happened before" relations
- each process knows order of local events, as timestamps are assigned to every event
- these timestamps can be lamport timestamps:
- or vector clocks:

I just don't know what to put behind lamport timestamps and vector clocks and generally what enables what, what implements what and why one can make competition visible and the other not. Can someone help me get an overview?

To look up definitions on wikipedia and reading scientific work has helped not that much...

Answer (score 1):

In distributed systems it is very hard to keep wall clocks in sync. Different applications have different tolerance for clock drift. For example, some distributed systems use clock to resolve conflicts (last update wins) and they accept the risk that clocks might not be in sync. But in some cases there are no tolerance.

As you correctly said, logical clocks were invented to address timing in distributed systems. There are two main problems to resolve: a) events needs to be totally ordered and b) detect concurrent events. Lamport timestamp addresses the total order problem; and vector clock helps to detect concurrent events.

So if I would create an index card, I would actually create several of them:

Global/Wall clock

- allows events to be ordered globally, but the risk is that clocks will get out of sync
- worth exploring how Cassandra deals with Last Updates Win strategy

Lamport timestamp

- this is a logical clock
- it allows total order of events
- (all other info on lamport timestamp)

Version clock

- this is a logical clock
- it allows detecting concurrent events
- (...note what "concurrent" means)
- all other info on vector clock
- not to be confused with version vector

Version vector

- ...

Comment: At first, thank you for your support. I think I want to focus exactly on Logical time, lamport timestamps and vector clocks for my exam, as they were the only topics that we discussed :D So as I get you right, Vector Clocks (I assume Version Clock = Vector Clocks?) and Lamport Timestamps ARE logical clocks that implement logical time? I thought both were just a kind of timestamps... I was also wondering about "it allows total order of events", as I've read that they allow only "partial" ordering of events? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: One other small thing, since I noticed that you seem to know something about the subject :D Assumption (my understanding so far): Asynchronous DS do not have a global clock, but use logical time. Synchronous DS use a global clock; but since clocks always have a certain drift rate, they know the exact drift rates and can therefore still use the clock. Are my assumptions correct? I find it super difficult to inform on the subject because everyone explains so strongly in technical terms...

Comment: 1. Lamport timestamp: usually node ids are used to make total order. If you use just a single counter, then the order is partial. Wikipedia has few notes on that.2. As for other stuff - both are logical clocks solving different problems.  3. Drift can be minimized, for example google's spanner database uses atomic clocks and gps (how neat the idea is!) to make sure the drift is minimal.

Comment: As a general statement - I prefer to think about DS as what is the problem and what are solutions; e.g. I need total order for my banking app - how can I get it? Wall clock might work, but some extra care will be needed. Or  can use lamport timestamp and that will give that to me.

Comment: I just realised I could not figure it out completely... could you explain to me in like a few sentences the relation between the three principles?

Comment: I don't think I totally understood the question. Let me try this way: a DS has multiple events, I need to order them, e.g. to replay later. I could use lamport timestamp. For example two nodes receive events at the same time: node1 set X=1; node2 set X=2. Then node 1 sends event to node 2: X=1. Node 2 will need to decide what is actual value for X; is it 1 or 2? So lamport timestamp will allow to order those update events, but won't help with detecting at node2 that there is a conflict. Version clock would help node2 to detect that there is a need to resolve a conflict around value of X.

Comment: I misspoke in last comment: "Then node 1 sends event to node 2: X=1. Node 2 will need to decide what is actual value for X; is it 1 or 2" - Node 2 actually does not know that x=1 and x=2 are concurrent events. That's where version clock gets useful. VC allows detection of concurrent events.